# Cant select free space on disk when installing Ubuntu Server

Tags: 18.04, server, partitioning, system-installation, 20.04

I want to install Ubuntu Server alongside Windows on a PC I have. I've done so before, except with Ubuntu Desktop, which I find easier to set up (in terms of partitioning). I have free space on my disk (not attached to any partition) of about 161GB.

This is what I mean - partitions 1-5 are for Windows, but I'm unable to select the free space.

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and what am I supposed to do?

## Update:

When going through the installation process on the same computer, but with Ubuntu *desktop*, I can select the free space and create partitions completely fine.

Comment: make sure your ssd is a basic disk and not a dynamic disk.(Also check whether you are using gpt partitioning.)

Comment: @ThulashitharanD I know it's a basic disk - The weird thing is, when trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 *desktop*, I can select the free space (and then create all the partitions) without any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

I just downloaded 16.04 server and upgraded to 20.04 from there. 16.04's setup is so much better and I could actually select the free space!

It's been a while since I installed Ubuntu Server on a PC but I still don't know what was really the problem.

(No offense, Canonical - your setup method for server 18.04 and above is kinda *bad*, bring back the 16.04-style installation!!!)